# Um checkbox pode ter mais de um value?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber de um checkbox pode ter mais de um value 
tipo exemplo abaixo para um com o nome do checkbox e outro com o preço . Fico grato desde já.

```
<td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Bolinho" value="15.75">Bolinho</td>
```

Comment: Não ..., qual seria o seu problema?

Comment: bem  no meu formulário ele tem apenas o nome da refeição a qual é inserida no mysql,  e depois pego ela e exibo todo o pedido em outra tela , mas eu queria colocar o preço também assim posso pegar o valor total também do pedido .

Comment: Bom, se pode resolver o seu problema de várias formas, precisa de um contexto maior. Trabalhar com dois valores e uma `tag` eu realmente nunca vi.

Comment: Nenhum campo pode ter mais de um valor, mas nada impede de em um valor você colocar mais de uma informação `value="pipoca|3.75"` e separar no lado do servidor depois. O caso é que não deveria precisar disso, pois se você mesmo está gerando a página, no lado do servidor já sabe qual ID ou nome do campo é de qual produto.

Comment: sim mais tipo, quando eu enviar o formulário no servidor tem as colunas pedido,quantidade e valor , assim poderia mostrar em tela o valor total do pedido e o que foi pedido .

Comment: você pode usar o campo `data-*`

Comment: Você já tem isso no servidor, não precisa mandar de volta.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio o que ele faz ? data-*

Comment: Alan, não acho que essa questão merecia negativo, pois acho que é uma dúvida válida e outros usuários podem se beneficiar dela, entretanto a sua dúvida na realidade, sua dúvida é ampla e vai desde o front-end(html) até o back-end(php/mysql).Vejo vc com algumas dúvidas que podem ser solucionadas aqui, mas explicar onde quer chegar e principalmente estudar os conceitos fundamentais dessas operações, nesse caso o CRUD, tente entender os fundamento(CREATE/READ/UPDATE/DELETE - Insert/Select/Update/Delete)

Comment: quais são exatamente as colunas da sua tabela?

Comment: refeicao,quantidade,bebida,quantidade, e quero colocar o preço com a quantidade total.@LeoCaracciolo

Comment: se tiver 2 refeições em uma mesa no banco vai salvar em duas linhas?

Comment: tipo tem cliente que pede várias refeições e elas são salvas na mesma linha . e a quantidade do mesmo jeito mas em outra linha , e assim por diante.

Comment: está confuso isso. As colunas da sua tabela são refeicao,quantidade,bebida,quantidade. Como salvar varias refeições na mesma linha e as quantidades em outra linha nessa estrutura de tabela?

Comment: veja se a resposta lhe serve

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não estou achando o código que você fez do pedido relacionado a essa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181148/como-enviar-dados-para-o-mysql-via-javascript?noredirect=1#comment374523_181148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer é isso:

### PHP

```
if (isset($_POST["numero_mesa"])) {

        $link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "DB");
        if($link->connect_errno){
             echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
             exit();
        }
        $numero_mesa=$_POST["numero_mesa"];

        foreach($_POST as $nome_campo => $valor){ 
            if(($nome_campo != "numero_mesa")&&($valor!="")){
                $nome_campo=str_replace("-"," ",$nome_campo);
                $aDest = explode("*", $nome_campo); 
                $nome_c=$aDest[0];
                $preco=$aDest[1];

                $sql = "INSERT INTO spedido(numero_mesa,pedido,quantidade,preco) VALUES('$numero_mesa','$nome_c','$valor','$preco')";
                $resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            }

        }
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Peixaria</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- function valida_form (){ if(document.getElementById("numero_mesa").value.length ==""){ alert('Por favor, preencha o campo Mesa'); document.getElementById("numero_mesa").focus(); return false } } //--> </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Peixaria</h1>
        <main>
            <header>
                <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
            </header>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="pedidos">
                    <form method="post" action="pedidos.php" onsubmit="return valida_form(this)">
                        <table border="0" id="table1">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" width="100"> <span>Mesa</span> <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa"> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="280" bgcolor="#FFEBC1">Refeição</td>
                                <td width="70" bgcolor="#FFEBC1">Quantidade</td>
                                <td width="150" bgcolor="#DFFFDF">Bebida</td>
                                <td width="70" bgcolor="#DFFFDF">Quantidade</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="280">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Costela-de-Tambaqui-sem-Espinha*20.00" size="7"></td>
                                <td width="150">Fanta Laranja 1l</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Fanta-Laranja-1l*8.00" size="7"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="280">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Lombo-de-Tambaqui-Frito-sem-Espinha*22.00"size="7"></td>
                                <td width="150">Fanta Laranja 2l</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Fanta-Laranja-2l*10.00" size="7"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="280">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Caldeirada-de-Tambaqui-sem-Espinha*30.00" size="7"></td>
                                <td width="150">Cola Cola 1l</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Cola-Cola-1l*12.00" size="7"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="280">Caldeirada de Tucunaré</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Caldeirada-de-Tucunaré*32.00" id="q4" size="7"></td>
                                <td width="150">Cola Cola 2l</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Cola-Cola-2l*14.00" size="7"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="280">Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Peixe-no-Tucupi-com-Camarão*35.00" size="7"></td>
                                <td width="150">Bare 2l</td>
                                <td width="70"><input type="text" name="Bare-2l*8.00" size="7"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" width="100"> <button class="btn" type="submit">Fazer Pedido</button> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tem que colocar uma coluna preco no Banco e os names dos inputs no html devem ser compostos conforme este exemplo: name="Costela-de-Tambaqui-sem-Espinha*20.00"  ,isto é, substituir espaços por tracinho -  nos nomes das refeições e bebidas seguido dos respectivos preços separados por asterisco *